# Why my controller doesn't intercept save row?

Tags: jquery, spring, jqgrid

I'm trying to do a edit inline with jQgrid, so I write this:

```
......
     colModel :[
               ........ 
               {name:'idProvino', index:'idProvino', editable: true}, 
               .......
               ],
    onSelectRow: function(id){
                     if(lastsel2 != null){
                         $('#listCong').jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2);
                     }

                    jQuery('#listCong').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
                    jQuery('#listCong').jqGrid('editRow',id,false);
                    lastsel2 = id;
                    },
editurl: '/mywebapp/controller/update/',
```

and this is my controller's method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public void update(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Long id,
                @RequestParam(value="idProvino", required=true) String idProvino, 
                @RequestParam(value="oper", required=true) String oper,
                final BindingResult bindingResult, 
                final Model uiModel, final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        DO SOMETHING
    }
```

But it not intercept request from jQgrid.. Why??

Using ispect tool of my browser I have this request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/controller/update/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Form Data: idProvino=5869&oper=edit&id=2
```

Comment: Where is your ajax.request that invokes "update" call in jQgrid ?

Comment: @PawełGłowacz it generated within jQgrid using editurl option into jqgrid..

Comment: Could you use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or developer tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to trace HTTP traffic between the server and the client. If you see what really will be sent to the server you can localize the origin of the problem: client or server code.

Comment: @Oleg I add request to question.. But seems correct to me...

Comment: I see that you have found the solution. My congratulations! HTTP trace helps to see where you should search for the origin of the problem and you have found the reason *yourself*. Fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it..

I have `BindingResult` into my method, but I didn't binding nothing so that is the problem....

So it works if I do in this way:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public void update(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) Long id,
                @RequestParam(value="idProvino", required=true) String idProvino, 
                @RequestParam(value="oper", required=true) String oper,final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        DO SOMETHING
    }
```